# SPI PWM LED driver

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, raspberry-pi, spi, rgb

I am looking for an integrated circuit that would connect via SPI to a Raspberry Pi (this should not be overly important besides 3,3V input logic and limited clock frequency). Target use is LED strip driving through a LED amplifier
It should have:

- 8 outputs
- output >=12V , low side switching
- not too exotic or outdated (available also in small quantities)
- generates pwm on its own
- minimum external components necessary
- connected together with MCP3208 (should not be an issue)
- possible to be hand soldered

So far I have looked at these:
MC33999 - good, but not sold anymore
MAX7219 - might work, but complicated overkill
WS2818B - functionally would suffice, but voltage levels do not match
TLC59711 - seems to be best, but not really hand solderable and current output (so not suitable for the led amplifier)

Any recommendations (from the list or other)?

Comment: WS2815. Powered 12V, but logical level 5V.

Comment: @user263983 that is the problem, need logical level 3.3V

Comment: You should be able level-shift a 3.3V signal to 5V to use the WS2815.

Comment: WS2815 seems to be an integration of driver IC and the diode and is only available as led strip, it does not seem to be available as separate IC to drive external led strips...

Comment: Buy strip, cut by pieces, level shifter with two transistors. Easy to control, no need power switches, no needs in PWM, individually controlled.

Comment: That is not really an option. Led strips are already installed (moreover in sauna so outside operating temperature). Currently driven by sw pwm from RPi's GPIO, but more GPIOs are needed and more importantly the sw pwm flickers sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESP32 has Wifi, so it is remotely controllable, and it has an excellent PWM with 16 outputs including HF dithering.

> TLC59711 - seems to be best, but not really hand solderable and current output (so not suitable for the led amplifier)

You can hack the current output into a voltage output, but it will be inverted. You can invert it back by connecting a resistor between the output and +3V3, and the output to the base of a bipolar transistor, that will give you an open collector output of the correct polarity. Or you can invert the PWM in software, in this case just replace the intended LED load with a resistor.

There's also [PCM9685](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9685.pdf), but it uses I2C, not SPI.

If you don't like SMD, you can find cheap modules with these chips pre-soldered.